# cypher query: return recipes rated by certain users, containing specific ingredients, ordered by number of recipes repeated in the result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing the below cypher query to return a few recipes with following conditions:

1. There is user 2203 and I can find similar users based on the sim_score.
2. Once the similar users are defined, I need to get a list of recipes that they rated.
3. The recipes from 2. should include all the following ingredients ['turmeric', 'salt'].
4. Recipes, then, should be ordered by the number of times that it showed up in the 1. (e.g. userB rated recipe 1,2,3 and userC rated recipe 2,4,5 => recipe 2 should be ordered first).

How can I do this?

```
query = """
    MATCH(u:USER {user:"2203"})-[s:SIMILARITY]->(u2:USER)-[:RATED]->(r:RECIPE)
    WITH count(r) as n_recipe
    WITH ["turmeric", "salt"] as ingredients
    WHERE exists((r.recipe)-[:CONTAINS]->(:INGREDIENT {name:ingredients}))
    return r.recipe
    ORDER BY n_recipe
    LIMIT 10
    """
graph.run(query)
```

Comment: what is wrong on your query? what is the expected result?

Comment: who is your teacher giving this homework? j/k

Comment: Never mind! sorted this out. query = """
    MATCH (r:RECIPE)<-[:RATED]-(u2:USER)<-[s:SIMILARITY]-(u:USER {user:"49"})
    WITH r, count(r.recipe) AS recipeCount, s.sim_score AS score
    ORDER BY recipeCount DESC, score DESC 
    
    WITH (r)
    MATCH (r)-[:CONTAINS]->(i:INGREDIENT)
    
    WITH r, collect(DISTINCT i.name) AS ingredients
    MATCH (r)
    WHERE all(x IN ['salt','garlic'] WHERE (x IN ingredients))
    RETURN r.name
    LIMIT 3
    """
graph.run(query)

Comment: Great job! Doing it is more fun :D